# How to change the position of text of factors in plot

Tags: r, plot, vector, graph, vegan

After I have made a constrained PCoA, and plotted the results in a graph, With the following result. However, the text is not nicely positioned at each location. Is there a possibility to modify this?

[image]

Code:

```
p = plot(ord, type="n") #Plot clean graph
with(env, levels(field)) #set the 3 different field levels
with(env, points(ord, display = "sites", col = colvec[field],pch = 19, bg = colvec[field], cex=1))#display sites with field collours
p = text(ord, display = "species", select = c(19, 50, 47, 13, 29, 12, 45), cex=0.8, col = "lightblue4") # add only some selected species
with(env, legend("topright", legend = levels(field), bty = "n",col = colvec, pch = 21, pt.bg = colvec)) #add legenda
plot(dbDRA, col = "black") #plot vectors
plot(dbDRA, p.max = 0.05, col = "red") #make all significant factors red
```

Comment: sadly I don't have enough points to post a picture in my question.  Hopefully the link works for you guys!

Comment: `?text` ... the `pos`, `adj` and `offset` parameters all allow you to adjust positioning of text

Comment: Which locations do you mean? The text is *exactly* where it should be: at the numerical coordinates of your result. If you move text, the locations differ from the result. However, in vegan you may look at functions `orditorp`, `ordipointlabel` and `orditkplot`. In addition, **ggplot2** graphics have functions that displace text from their correct locations to avoid overplotting.